# How can I save a downloaded file to a specified path?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

When using  `files = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(Path).Children.Request().GetAsync();`

the file downloaded get saved in the `C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Packages\4a9bc9b3-6484-4443-9a65-f36f7519b1d5_9b10f1p8kdmhr\AC\INetCache\3HUY71XE`

```
public static async Task<System.IO.Stream > GetCurrentUserFileAsync(string Path, string FileName)
{
    IDriveItemChildrenCollectionPage files = null;
    try
    {
        var graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
        files = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(Path).Children.Request().GetAsync();
        foreach (DriveItem item in files)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Got file: " + item.Name);
            if (item.Name == FileName )
            {
                var fileContent = await DownloadFileAsync(item.Id);
                return fileContent ;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    catch (ServiceException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("We could not get user files: " + e.Error.Message);
        return null;
    }


}

// Downloads the content of an existing file.
public static async Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(string fileId)
    {
        Stream fileContent = null;

        try
        {
            var graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
            var downloadedFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[fileId].Content.Request().GetAsync();
            fileContent = downloadedFile;
            Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded file content for file: " + fileId);


        }

        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("We could not download the file. The request returned this status code: " + e.Error.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

Comment: What is the definition of DownloadFileAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution was to use this code using ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path because we are not allowed to write files anywhere else then relative path to the application:

```
 public static async Task<bool> TryDownloadFileAtPathAsync()
    {
        var createdFileId = await UserSnippets.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), STORY_DATA_IDENTIFIER);
        var fileContent = await UserSnippets.GetCurrentUserFileAsync("/Documents","Imp.zip") ;
        using (var fileStream = await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Create(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\Imp.zip")))
        {
            fileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
       return fileContent != null;
    }
```

For detailed information to Application's relative path one can lookup this page: [ApplicationData   Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata)

Thanks @RasmusW

Answer (score 0):

If `await DownloadFileAsync(item.Id)` retrieves the file in the resulting stream, then it is up to the caller of your method `GetCurrentUserFileAsync` to write the stream contents somewhere.

That can be done using this code

```
var fileContent = await GetCurrentUserFileAsync(onedrivepath, onedrivefilename);
using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\localpath\\localfilename"))
{
    fileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: My code for saving the file is:

        `using (var fileStream = await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Create("C:\\Temp\\Imp.zip")))
              {
                    fileContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
              }`

But I get an error message saying the the acces is denied.
Users.Download File at specified path failed. Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Temp' is denied.
I have tried different path but it always fail with the same error message.

Comment: Sounds like the user running the process needs write access to the folder.

Comment: Actually I found out that I can only write files to a folder relative to the application. It's not related to the user's folder access rights.